# How to handle weird socket request (HTTP server)

Tags: c#, .net, http

I've written my own HTTP server to embed in a desktop application and it works (spins up a server on localhost), except that I'm getting a strange request on the socket that is causing the connection to be closed so that no new requests are being handled.  The request is occuring about 15 seconds after I open the web page.  The packet contains a long series of `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0......` when I examine it.  I have no idea what's causing this or how to handle it.  For those first 15 seconds, I'm able to do everything I need to do, but once this happens, no new requests can be made and the server won't respond to any new requests.  It also doesn't happen every time I launch the application but I can't pin down why.

```
while (true)
{
    //Accept a new connection
    Socket mySocket = _listener.AcceptSocket();
    if (mySocket.Connected)
    {
        Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024];
        int i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);
        string sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bReceive); 
        if (sBuffer.Substring(0, 3) != "GET")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sBuffer);
            mySocket.Close();
            return;
        }    
        ........handle valid requests
    }    
}
```

Comment: `have no idea what's causing this`. Because you don't use the `i` returned from `Receive` when using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString`. You just assume you have read `bReceive.Length` bytes....

Comment: Classic 'TCP is stream based' issue. What you receive might not be the whole message or might not fill your buffer and so on..

Comment: @L.B ah, I see what you're talking about.  Careless mistake, thanks

Comment: That long series of `\0` that you're getting is likely a result of reading less than 1024 bytes of data.  i.e. there's only 100 bytes of data, so you'll have 924 instances of `/0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    //Accept a new connection
    Socket mySocket = _listener.AcceptSocket();
    if (mySocket.Connected)
    {
        Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024];
        int i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0);
        if(i > 0) // added check to make sure data is received
        {
            string sBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bReceive, 0, i); // added index and count
            if (sBuffer.Substring(0, 3) != "GET")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(sBuffer);
                mySocket.Close();
                return;
            }    
            ........handle valid requests
        }
    }    
}
```

Ultimately - you will need to do something if `i == 1024` - because if it does, there is more data than you are reading in `mySocket.Receive`.

As a side note - I might change 
`if (sBuffer.Substring(0, 3) != "GET")`
to 
`if (sBuffer.StartsWith("GET"))`

It's slightly easier to read - and has the added benefit of not requiring a change to the substring length if (for some odd reason) GET changed to something else.

Edit - this will allow for multiple calls to `mySocket.Receive` when more data than 1024 bytes is encountered:

```
        while (true)
        {
            //Accept a new connection
            Socket mySocket = _listener.AcceptSocket();
            if (mySocket.Connected)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Byte[] bReceive = new Byte[1024];
                int i;
                while ((i = mySocket.Receive(bReceive, bReceive.Length, 0) > 0))
                {
                    sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bReceive, 0, i)); // added index and count
                }
                string sBuffer = sb.ToString();
                if (sBuffer.Substring(0, 3) != "GET")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sBuffer);
                    mySocket.Close();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mike sorry not good enough. 1) *mySocket.Receive* will never return a value <=0 till connection is closed(so an interactive protocol is not posiible) 2) Second part of my first comment. What if the bytes [95,150] is splitted(sent in two different packets) for char 'Ö' in a long string.

Comment: BTW: Who deleted previous comments and why?

Comment: Not me.  Must have been a mod.

Comment: I'm still waiting at the edge of my seat for your silver bullet answer rather than just comments.

Comment: Mike, you answer is already *accepted*. So no need to spend time for nothing... But Just a Hint: `new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream())`. Its *ReadLine* method can solve all these problems :)

Comment: BTW: to write a home-made HTTP server, there are better ways of doing it like *HttpListener*.